# Saving python list of numpy arrays of different sizes to .txt-file

Tags: python, list, pandas, numpy

I am looking for a nice way to save multiple 1D numpy arrays of different lengths in a .txt-file (each array being one column). I currently have all of them placed in a python list.
np.columnstack and np.savetxt don't work for arrays of different sizes and so far the only way I got it to work was by filling up the arrays with zeros to make them equally long.

I also found a suggested solution that uses DataFrames from Pandas and then saves it to a cvs put that messes up the formatting in the rows that don't have an entry in each column.

Comment: What is your data looking like?

Comment: What exactly do you want the format of the text file to be? Like a CSV? And what should 'empty' spaces in the columns look like?

Comment: I want the columns to be separated by a tab and empty spaces should just be skipped so entries don't show up outside of the column they are supposed to be in. For example if there was no entry in the first column the entry in the second column would shift to the left.

Comment: The data are floats.

Comment: Give a sample, including desired display.  And use `,` instead of tab so the display is unambiguous.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Direct file write might be easiest

```
In [233]: alist=[[1,2,3,4],[.2,.4,1.2],['a','b','c','d','e']]
In [234]: import itertools
In [235]: list(itertools.zip_longest(*alist))
Out[235]: 
[(1, 0.2, 'a'),
 (2, 0.4, 'b'),
 (3, 1.2, 'c'),
 (4, None, 'd'),
 (None, None, 'e')]
In [236]: 
In [236]: list(itertools.zip_longest(*alist,fillvalue=''))
Out[236]: [(1, 0.2, 'a'), (2, 0.4, 'b'), (3, 1.2, 'c'), (4, '', 'd'), ('', '', 'e')]
```

Now just write formatted lines (substitute `file.write` for the print):

```
In [238]: for line in itertools.zip_longest(*alist,fillvalue=''):
     ...:     print('%5s, %5s, %5s'%tuple(line))
     ...:     
    1,   0.2,     a
    2,   0.4,     b
    3,   1.2,     c
    4,      ,     d
     ,      ,     e
```